# Webhook security vs API security

Tags: api, security, stripe-payments, webhooks, hmac

While I see most of the service providers call webhooks with HMAC signature, the same service providers don't have HMAC supported in their own API. In fact, their API can be called just by passing the API secret in headers. For example, Stripe only accepts API secret in their API whereas Stripe calls webhooks with HMAC signature. Why Stripe does not support passing HMAC signature too while calling their APIs as it is done in their webhooks?

Comment: In Stripe's case, this is probably just a design choice they made when building their API.

Comment: Some providers _do_ use a token for webhooks. Examples, along with why signatures might be preferred (to mitigate risk of replay attacks) are given on e.g. https://hookdeck.com/webhooks/guides/what-are-the-webhook-authentication-strategies#which-webhook-authentication-strategies-should-i-use.

Comment: I know HMAC is beneficial to avoid MIM and replay attacks can be avoided too by passing some unique ID or timestamp, I am baffled that stripe does not support HMAC in their own API but recommends clients verify webhooks using HMAC